# SSIS Execute SQL Task Stored Procedure returning empty result sets

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a simple stored procedure that returns 1 row with 3 columns. I am trying to create an SSIS package that reuses the values in these columns later. If I run a simple select query everything is happy but when I run the stored procedure I get the following error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "rs_UpdateMemberExtract"
>   failed with the following error: "Unable to populate result columns
>   for single row result type. The query returned an empty result set.".
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet"
>   property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or
>   connection not established correctly.

I've set up an ado.net connection and the proc runs correctly in SSMS, I have the task set up like follows:

```
ConnectionType: ADO.NET
Connection: ServerName.connectionName
SQLSourceType: Direct Input
SQLstatment: Name of Proc (rs_UpdateMemberExtract)
IsQueryStoredProcedure: True
```

I have each parameter mapped to a variable and the direction set to Output

I have the name of each column that should be returned in the result set and mapped to the associated variable.

The task works if I set the ResultSet to 'None',

Any ideas What I've missed?

Thanks

Comment: What do you literally have for SQLStatement?   I hope not "Name of Proc (rs_UpdateMemberExtract)".    It should just be "dbo.rs_UpdateMemberExtract".

Comment: haha that would be silly, I have dbo.rs_UpdateMemberExtract

Comment: Ok, now why do you have the parameters direction set to Output?   Your stored procedure returns output parameters, or a resultset, or both?  What are you setting ResultSet to?   Sounds like it should be set to "Single Row".

Comment: Initially it was returning output parameters but it doesn't know. I have changed this. It returns a 1 row with 3 columns of data. I have the ResultSet set to single row. Yet still get the same error as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an SQL Task Editor expects results returned in a row … but there are no records to return then the following SQL fills a null return with a space. Note : can also be used to return zero if a numeric “return row” is expected

```
SELECT '' + ISNULL ((SELECT x FROM y WHERE (z = ?)), '') AS  myfield
```